# Is it possible to have a button on Object's detail page that redirects to Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, custom-button

I have created a Lightning Component Bundle and a button on detail page of an Object. On clicking the button, is there any possible ways such that it redirects to Lightning page of the created Lightning Bundle.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can simply do a javascript url redirect using the lightning url format and it should do the trick. The format is

```
https://<lightning.domain.com>/lightning/r/Account/<recordID>/view
```

OR

```
https://<lightning.domain.com>/lightning/o/Account/home
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/heres-need-know-new-url-format-lightning.html)

Comment: Let me know how you get on, and if you found it useful be sure to mark the question.

Comment: Great stuff happy to hear it, mark it as answered if you could.